# Set image source

Tags: c#, wpf, image, windows-store-apps, imagesource

I am trying to set image source to something from my computer (not in the assets).
This is how I am trying to do this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(@"D:\Riot Games\about.png", UriKind.Absolute);
ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);

this.image1.Source = imgSource;
```

I tried almost everything I could find in the internet but nothing seem to work.

Any idea why?

XAML:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App11.VideoPreview"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App11"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="250"
    d:DesignWidth="250">

    <Grid>
        <Button Height="250" Width="250" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Name="image1" Height="250" Width="250"/>
                <Grid Margin="0,-74,0,0">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0" Opacity="0.75">
                            <GradientStop Color="Black"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#FF5B5B5B" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Grid.Background>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="textBox1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="test" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" Foreground="White" Padding="5"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: It must work. Could you show use .xaml?

Comment: May be it is due to user rights? Try to run .exe as administartor.

Comment: Ran the visual studio as administrator. is that enough? (it didnt work aswell). I dont know how to run this metro app as administrator

Comment: Why are you setting image source in XAML and code behind at same time?

Comment: @RohitVats, does it matter? in the XAML i just checked how it will look like. I removed it now (also edited my post). It doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot access disk drives directly from your windows metro apps. Extracted from [File access permissions in windows store apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)

> You can access certain file system locations, like the app install
>   directory, app data locations, and the Downloads folder, with Windows
>   Store apps by default. Apps can also access additional locations
>   through the file picker, or by declaring capabilities.

But there are some special folders which you can access like `Pictures library`, documents library etc. by enabling capabilities from your package manifest file. So, this code will work after enabling pictures library from manifest file (copy about.png file in pictures library folder)

```
    private async void SetImageSource()
    {
        var file = await 
          Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFileAsync("about.png");
        var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync();
        var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);

        image1.Source = bitmapImage;
    }
```

But ideal solution would be to include you file in you application and set its build action to Content so that it can be copied in your **Appx** folder along with other content files. Then you can set the image source like this -

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        Uri uri = new Uri(BaseUri, "about.png");
        BitmapImage imgSource = new BitmapImage(uri);
        this.image1.Source = imgSource;
    }
```

OR you can simply do this in XAML only :

```
<Image x:Name="image1" Source="ms-appx:/about.png"/>
```

---

Here is list of special folders which you can access from your application -

1. **Local App data**
2. **Roaming app data**
3. **Temporary app data**
4. **App installed location**
5. **Downloads folder**
6. **Documents library**
7. **Music library**
8. **Pictures library**
9. **Videos library**
10. **Removable devices**
11. **Home group**
12. **Media Server devices**

To enable capabilities from your manifest file, double click on `Package.appxmanifest` file in your solution and check `Pictures Library` checkbox under capabilities tab to enable it for your application. Likewise you can do it for other folders which you want to access.

[image]

Comment: I get the images from the whole computer, I cant put them in specific place or embedded them in my assets.

Comment: I'm afraid that ain't possible with restriction in place for metro apps.

Comment: I managed to set image source using StorageFile. but now there's another problem. how can I set StorageFile using direct uri instead filepicker?

Comment: That's what I mentioned in the answer - `Apps can also access additional locations through the file picker and not directly through URI apart from special folders`. Setting image source directly will compile fine but it will crash at runtime stating that you don't have access to the folder.

Comment: I understand. best solution is to put all the files I want to access in special folders such as videos library or pictures library or w/e I want, but I still cant set image source directly even when the image is in the special folder I get the System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied error.

Comment: Yeah for that you need to enable the capabilities from your manifest file. Double click on `Package.appxmanifest` file in your solution and check `Pictures Library` checkbox under capabilities tab to enable it for your application.

Comment: Added image for the same in answer.

Comment: Saw it, thank you. I am pretty sure I saw it before but didnt read about that :P thank you very much!.