# Windows Store App image is not visible

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I create image like this:

```
<Image Source="C:\Users\me\Pictures\Logo.png" Width="160" Height="90" Stretch="Fill"/>
```

I marked Pictures Library in Capabilities tab in manifest file.

I've tried to do the same programatically, using BitmapImage, but also no results.

Please, help me.

Comment: I had similar problem, win 8 application can not directly access files on the disk. This post describes a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18419269/3004466

Comment: I was looking for this solution. Than you very much. I will store my files in app data location.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Windows Store development, and I have only been working through tutorials on Windows Phone, but it seems to me that the store app image should not be located in a location like this.

In my Windows Phone apps, the image was located within the Visual Studio project as part of the app package, and the path was something like /Assets/Images/Logo.png, rather than a hard link to a location on disk (that, in this location, a user could easily delete since it's a part of their personal pictures directory).

I'm not 100% certain on all this since I'm new to it too, but it seems like the SDK really just doesn't like what you're doing because it's probably bad practice.

If you're looking to do more than just store your static app logo, Fedor's answer should be helpful.

Comment: Logo file was just example. I'd simply like to have access to some directories. I will use app data directory. Thanks ;)