# Win 8 App Set text in data template

Tags: c#, listview, windows-8, datatemplate

Im trying to learn how to make datatemplate in listviews in my win 8 app

I have the following code in my Xaml code

```
<!-- Vertical scrolling item list -->
    <ListView x:Name="itemListView"
      Margin="120,0,0,60"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
      SelectionChanged="ItemListView_SelectionChanged">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="110" Margin="6">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="110" Height="110">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    </Border>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subtitle}"  TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}"  MaxHeight="60" FontFamily="Global User Interface"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

What I cant work out is how to set the text for the three text blocks Title,Subtitle & Description as well as the Picture in Image

Usually When the page loads I use the following in my itemListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) method

```
itemListView.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(correct) + ". " + line.Split(',')[6]);
```

But how do I do it Im really stumped

Any help appreciated

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make a class which includes those properties.

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Subtitle { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

Then when you add items:

```
var item = new MyItem();
item.Title = "Title";
item.Subtitle = "Subtitle";
item.Description = "Some example description.";
item.Source = "Assets/SomeFolder/SomeImage.png";
itemListView.Items.Add(item);
```

That worked in my app ([AirPett Transit](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/airpett-transit/7f36e3cf-1b7b-405a-8b5d-4075672a0870))

Comment: Thanks for the help I Put the class in the same page.cs that my itemlistviewloaded methodd is in and added the code. It runs with no errors but when the page opens the listview is blank Any Ideas?

Comment: I see, you are missing a reference to the 'itemListView_Loaded'-event handler. You should add it into your XAML: `Loaded="itemListView_Loaded"`.

Comment: Your a star that works one thing I tried item.Source = "C:\\Users\\Mark\\Pictures\\Ricards-13-02-2015-03-18-12.jpg"; to load a picture into the image but it doesnt show

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot access disk drives directly from your windows store apps. You must add the images to be displayed into the Project folder (i.e. Assets) or use the special access to some libraries. Please see these two links: [File access permissions in windows store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx) and [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18417897/set-image-source)

Comment: That means:

The XAML and the C# code are both correct and working, but this problem is a limitation of the Windows Apps platform.

As this resolved the original problem with the data bindings and -template, please mark this as answer and upvote if helpful ;)

I'm glad to help you and just tell me if there is another problem that can be fixed (the one above with the file loading can't be, as the problem is in the .net framework).

Comment: Thanks for the help I cannot load pics into asset as there could be over 100 and 1-2mb each I load from c drive into an image in other parts of my app so I cant understand why I cant here I do some research anyway thanks again